# generic return object

Tags: java, collections

Recently I was reading the following piece of code from oracle collection tutorial when i came across this piece of code.

```
public static <E> Set<E> removeDups(Collection<E> c) {
             return new LinkedHashSet<E>(c);
}
```

I was not able to understand why the returned value is something

```
            <E> Set<E> and not just Set<E> ?
```

Comment: Java Tutorials article on generic methods: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The return type is, in fact, simply `Set<E>`.**

The other `<E>` is there to indicate that this is a generic method, and to state that `E` is a parameter to the generic. Without this `<E>`, the compiler would assume that `E` is an existing class, and would try to locate it (producing an error if no class named `E` is in scope).

Answer (score 2):

It *is* just `Set`, a set with elements of type `E` to be more precise. The extra `<E>` in front of the return type is the type declaration for that method, specifying that the type `<E>` is to be used only in the scope of this particular method - not to be confused with a class' type parameter, like this one:

```
public class Example<E> {
```

In the above snippet, the type parameter `<E>` is visible for all the methods in the class, whereas a type declaration like the one in your question, is visible only in that method.

Answer (score 2):

the return type is `Set<E>` not `<E> Set<E>`. The first `<E>` declare the generic type variable `E`, while for other `<E>`s attached to collection classes are using that declaration.

Answer (score 0):

E may be a class. By returning the `<E> Set<E>` you are declaring that E is a parameter in the generic.

This is a static function, so there is no underlying definition of what E is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the first  seems a bit weird.  One way of thinking about the first  is that it says (or reminds you) that *the compiler will figure out E for itself*, based upon the type of the passed in Collection, and you, the user, don't need to explicitly tell it what E is.